# Pass Local Image Path as URL in Facebook SDK

Tags: python, image, facebook, external-url

I need to use an image I have stored in my PC as thumbnail to post some content to facebook. The problem is

```
graph.put_object(group_id, connection_name = "feed", message = posttext, link = url, picture = r"C:\Users\Fluffy\Desktop\img.png")
```

When I use this path in picture, it returns:

```
GraphAPIError: (#100) picture should represent a valid URL
```

So, is there anyway to fake a local url (or even an image generated in memory using PIL) as external url? Or the only way is to upload it to somewhere and get static link.

Comment: No, you can not use a local file, only a publicly reachable HTTP(S) URL will work.

Comment: @CBroe Do you know some free service of image upload that has a python API?